# How to copy and rename a file in same directory?

Tags: powershell, scripting

My folder C:\Downloads\Files\ has 3 .zip files.

- test1.zip
- test2.zip
- test3.zip

I need to copy these files into same location and append another extension `.dat` to the file.

The total files in my folder `C:\Downloads\Files\` should have 6 files now (3 .zip and 3.dat)

- test1.zip
- test2.zip
- test3.zip
- test1.zip.dat
- test2.zip.dat
- test3.zip.dat

Can anyone help me get this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to retrieve all zip files and copy them using the `Copy-Item` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Downloads\Files\' -Filter '*.zip' | 
    Copy-Item -Destination { "$($_.Name).dat" }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following copies **only** files from within the `$path` directory with extension `.dat`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$($_.FullName).dat"}
```